# Medição de tempo no Windows

Tags: c++, windows

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de medir o tempo de execução de um programa em C++. Encontrei diversas soluções na internet, cada uma com uma abordagem. Sugestões?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para Windows especificamente, a melhor forma (no sentido de possuir maior resolução) é usar o 
[`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Um exemplo do uso (use um compilador recente):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

class Watch
{
    public:
        Watch()
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER li;
            if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
            {
                std::cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";
                return;
            }

            mPCFreq = static_cast<double>(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
            mCounterStart = li.QuadPart;
        }

        // Retorna o tempo em milisegundos desde que o
        // objeto Watch foi criado.
        double getCounter()
        {
            LARGE_INTEGER li;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
            return static_cast<double>(li.QuadPart - mCounterStart)/mPCFreq;
        }

    private:
        uint64_t mCounterStart;
        double mPCFreq;
};

int main()
{
    Watch counter;
    Sleep(1000);
    std::cout << counter.getCounter() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Nesse caso, o código retorna o tempo em milissegundos entre a criação do objeto `Watch` e a chamada `counter.getCounter()`.

---

Outra solução mais portável é usar a biblioteca [boost](http://www.boost.org/) e usar `boost::posix_time::time_duration` para medir o tempo na escala que você desejar (milisegundos, microsegundos, segundos).

Comment: Algumas recomendações: 1. Sempre que possível (isto é, se o compilador suportar), deve-se usar os tipos em `stdint.h`, como `int64`, em vez de `__int64`. 2. Devem-se evitar usar variáveis globais para este tipo de coisa. Fazer `CounterStart` uma variável local e passá-la para o `main` com um `return` e para o `GetCounter` como argumento seria melhor.

Comment: @luiscubal Fiz umas alterações no código. É uma abordagem diferente. O que acha?

Comment: Bem melhor, embora o `cout` no construtor não seja ideal (uma exceção seria preferível). Já agora, em caso de erro, é possível obter uma mensagem mais detalhada com `GetLastError` e `FormatMessage` com `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`.

Comment: @luiscubal, de acordo com a [documentação das funções](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905(v=vs.85).aspx), versões posteriores ao XP não causarão erro ao invocar essa função da API. O código está OK então.

Comment: @lfelix O `QueryPerformanceCounter` é chamado uma vez só no contrutor. O outro, que você deve ter confundido, é o `QueryPerformanceFrequency`, que obtém a frequência.

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, acabei editando o comentário. Entendi o código, resolveu meu problema. Só uma informação, esse valor retornado está em qual escala de tempo, miliseconds? Ainda não implementei...

Comment: Isso. Em milissegundos.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 provê [high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock), é a solução ideal porém a microsoft ainda não provê uma implementação correta que use QueryPerformanceCounter. [Isto é considerado um bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/719443), e parece que será resolvido na próxima versão do visual studio. Portanto no momento melhor usar QueryPerformanceCounter diretamente ou [uma biblioteca cuja implementação use](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/chrono/users_guide.html#chrono.users_guide.tutorial.specific_clocks.high_resolution_clock).

Comment: Utilizar o QueryPerformanceCounter do MingW pode resolver esse problema?

Comment: @lfelix o QueryPerformanceCounter do MinGW dever ser o mesmo do nativo Windows.

Answer (score 0):

O texto([`Optimizing software in C++`](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf) - recomendo ler) mostra como podemos alcançar isso.

Traduzido:

> As medidas de tempo podem requerer uma resolução muito alta, se os intervalos de tempo são curtas. No Windows, você pode usar as funções [`GetTickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ou [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para resolução de milissegundos. A resolução muito maior pode ser obtido com o contador de carimbo de tempo na CPU, que conta com a freqüência do relógio da CPU.

Há um problema que *a frequência do relógio pode variar de forma dinâmica e que as medições são instáveis ​​devido a interrupções e switches da tarefa*.

---

É interessante olhar também para a classe [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) que é baseada em duas *API's*, a [`QueryPerformanceFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) e [`QueryPerformanceCounter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).